# unsupported locale setting python/django. how to solve this?

Tags: django, python-2.5

File "C:\PYTHON25\lib\locale.py", line 478, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)

Error: unsupported locale setting.
im using windows7 OS.
how to solve this problem ??

Comment: Please format your question and cleanly separate code, traceback and your question. Also please give us more information about settings (eg. [`LANGUAGE_CODE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code)).

Answer (score 1):

Locale libraries must be set at system that you're using. To check which locales installed use:

```
locale -a
```

If you don't see locale that you want to use install it. Here you can find more https://askubuntu.com/a/76106